# Powershell script to remove expired certs from a single server

Tags: powershell, certificate

Can someone please provide some assistance; I am trying to remove expired certs.

```
$ListOfServer = Get-Content "C:\Temp\expired_certs\Test.pfx"
Foreach($Server in $ListOfServer) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
        # Get Certificate list and assign to a variable
        $Certs = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Recurse
        # Loop through each object in $Certs
        Foreach($Cert in $Certs) {
            # If The objects property "NotAfter" is older than the current time, delete
            If($Cert.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)) {
                $Cert | Remove-Item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:34

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name -ScriptBlock
CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) \[Invoke-Command\], ParameterBindingValidationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId:ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: so you have a list of computer names in a `pfx` file? are you sure you're reading the correct file?

Comment: It's only a single server. I'm kinda new at this. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: no, your code looks good, the error you see happens because there is likely an empty line in your file. also `.pfx` is definitely not the best extension for a text file having a list of servers ;) thats gonna be very confusing for someone else reading your code

Comment: Okay thank you, let me work on fixing that. Let me make it a .txt file.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon  Do you think I need the listofservers line? I need to delete old certs on just one server. What would you suggest I use

Comment: No not really if its just one server you dont need a file with servers, can just use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName theServerHere -ScriptBlock { ... }`